# how to change Socket read timeout?

Tags: java, sockets, timeout, jakarta-mail

I use JavaMail API like there:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
prop.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", "2000");
Session session = Session.getInstance(prop, null);
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp"); 
transport.connect()
```

i don't use `Socket` object directly so how can i change socket read timeout ?

---

StackTrace:

```
org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPConnection.receiveLine(SMTPConnection.java:760)
org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPConnection.receiveLine(SMTPConnection.java:682)
org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPConnection.getReply(SMTPConnection.java:692)
org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPConnection.getWelcome(SMTPConnection.java:448)
org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPConnection.protocolConnect(SMTPConnection.java:143)
org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:165)
javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:274)
controller.RegisterController.isAuthorized(RegisterController.java:132)
controller.RegisterController.register(RegisterController.java:102)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:68)
javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1028)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:286)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1375)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:752)
org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:38)
org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170)
org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem by changing to the newest version of JavaMail (to JavaMail 1.5). I write about it there: http://openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/Which-version-of-JavaMail-td4665285.html

thank's everybody for help, specially to Bill Shannon :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the mail.smtp.timeout property.  See the [javadocs for the com.sun.mail.smtp package](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html).

Comment: when i replace `prop.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", 1000);` by `prop.put("mail.smtp.timeout", 1000);` to my code, nothing happened. I have to wait 5 min again to catch `javax.mail.MessagingException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out` i use JavaMail 1.5

Comment: You probably want to keep both timeouts.  Are you using exactly the code above?  What's the debug output show?

Comment: used code `Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
            prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            prop.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", "3000");
            prop.put("mail.smtp.timeout", "3000");
            Session session = Session.getInstance(prop, null);
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(server, 587, login, pass);`

Comment: i start debug, it stop at `transport.connect(server, 587, login, pass);` and after 5 min i catch exception: `"javax.mail.MessagingException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out"`

Comment: Are you sure you're using the JavaMail reference implementation?  What's the debug output show?  From the stack trace above it looks like you might be using the GNU version of JavaMail.  Are you running on Linux?

Comment: i get JavaMail reference implementation from https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home, i write about it there: http://openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/Which-version-of-JavaMail-td4665285.html

Comment: You  might've done something wrong.  Show me the debug output so we can see if it's actually picking up the correct jar file.  Or show me a new stack trace that doesn't include any "geronimo" classes.

Comment: I get javax.mail.jar from the https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home again and change it and now everything ok. So the problem was with a  pretty old version of JavaMail

Answer (score -1):

Previously I have worked with JAVAMAIL API.I think you want to increase the socket timeout due to connection timeout error runtime.But it is not due to this problem instead an important learning was that when we need to execute a larger request in any application we should not use them directly on main thread instead, one should create an asynchronous child thread and execute the request like emails on the same and then update the main thread after result is obtained.

Comment: No, he wants to change the *read* timeout. Do read the question. You can't increase the default connection timeout in any case, only decrease it.

Comment: whats the difference between socket read timeout and connection timeout ??

Comment: If you don't know the difference you shouldn't be answering questions about it. Connect timeout is a timeout during connect. Read timeout is a timeout during a read. It's not difficult.